# I get an ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199) error for getter length

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to send the username and surname to an API to check login details and return a message. The app runs but it does nothing and gives this message

The Error i get is /flutter ( 9980): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 9980): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 9980): Tried calling: length

the Code is below

```
  startLogin() async {
    String apiurl = ""; //api url
    //dont use http://localhost , because emulator don't get that address
    //insted use your local IP address or use live URL
    //hit "ipconfig" in windows or "ip a" in linux to get you local IP


    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(apiurl), body: {
      'username': email, //get the username text
      'password': password  //get password text
    });

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var jsondata = json.decode(response.body);
      if(jsondata["error"]){
        setState(() {
          showprogress = false; //don't show progress indicator
          error = true;
          errormsg = jsondata["message"];
        });
      }else{
        if(jsondata["success"]){
          setState(() {
            error = false;
            showprogress = false;
          });
          //save the data returned from server
          //and navigate to home page


          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SearchPage(),),);
          //user shared preference to save data
        }else{
          showprogress = false; //don't show progress indicator
          error = true;
          errormsg = "Something went wrong.";
        }
      }
    }else{
      setState(() {
        showprogress = false; //don't show progress indicator
        error = true;
        errormsg = "Error during connecting to server.";
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: On what line does the code break ?

Comment: @esentis it does not say , does not break but rather noting is done and on console you can see that message

Comment: Make your debugger stop on uncaught exceptions and you will see where it crashes.